# When did cel shading enter Breath of the Wild's design?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm curious at what point and how it was decided that Zelda: Breath of the Wild would use [cel shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading).

[image]

I found that the technique was first used in a video game in 1996 ([ZPC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C-ecUjpKGk)), but I'm having trouble finding any information about its introduction to Zelda: BOTW. (Most of the search results are about a hack that removes cel shading from the game.) Does anyone remember there being any interviews or articles that talked about the graphics, pre- or post-release of the game? Or might be better at Googling than I am?

Comment: The Wikipedia page has some information as to why they did this for _The Legend of Zelda The Wind Waker_: " In the case of The Legend of Zelda: The Wind Waker, developer Satoru Takizawa states that using this style made it easier to "represent the mechanisms and objects for puzzles [in The Wind Waker] in a more easy-to-understand way". Takizawa also argues that photorealistic graphics, in contrast, would have "had the adverse effect of making information difficult to represent game-wise"

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize they used for a previous Zelda! Thank you.